# Wordpress archive permalink with leaf category

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Wordpress Category Archive permalinks set up with %category% include the full category tree. I want to see only the leaf category in the URL, not the full tree.

Example:

```
Wordpress Category: recipes > baking > bread
current permalink for archive: domain.com/recipes/baking/bread
desired permalink: domain.com/bread
```

I've been searching the web without any idea how to hook or filter this change into my wordpress code, so any ideas and help is highly welcome.
thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found the answer, in case someone else has a similar issue. The following code will leave only the deepest category in the archive permalink and will remove all parent categories.

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'wpse7807_category_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse7807_category_link( $catlink, $category_id )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $catlink = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();

    if ( empty( $catlink ) ) {
        $catlink = home_url('?cat=' . $category_id);
    } else {
        $category = &get_category( $category_id );
        $category_nicename = $category->slug;

        $catlink = str_replace( '%category%', $category_nicename, $catlink );
        $catlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $catlink, 'category' ) );
    }
    return $catlink;
}
```

kudos to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/changing-the-category-permalink-structure.